# ActionBarStyle from style.xml with AppCompat v7 support library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I searched whole web. Tried tens of solutions. I also followed documentation of Android but I couldn't manage to do want I need. **I just want to make actionbar background gradient**. I made my drawable xml file:

**action_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="@color/colorActionBarStart"
        android:endColor="@color/colorActionBarEnd" />
</shape>
```

**My style.xml:**

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarStyle"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I saw same thing many times with android. There are tons of answers but none of them works. What I'm trying to do is just make a gradient background for actionbar. Isn't there anybody done this before with appcompat v7 library? Why is this so hard? 
May be I can't get because I'm so new at android development. If this is the case tell me right point of view.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: I haven't done it your way. However, if i do this, I'll use a theme with no action bar for the activity, then use a coordinator layout. Inside that layout you can use app bar layout to host your customised toolbar. This way, you can make the action bar whatever you like

Comment: @AnkyAn I tried that too and I used toolbar style but it did not work. My aim is to do it from styles.xml. How could you do that? Can you send me your style.xml? I don't want to use inline style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do not use the default action bar provided by a theme like `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Instead, I'll do this:

- Use a theme like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
- Include a `<Toolbar>` tag in my layout
- Call `setSupportActionBar()` and pass my toolbar

This lets me set the background of my toolbar directly in my layout file. That said...

I tried playing around with the base themes you posted, and I was also unable to set the background of the default actionbar using styles. However, I got a gradient working by deleting the `actionBarStyle` theme item and just doing it in Java, in `onCreate()`:

```
Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.action_bar);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

If your goal is to do this for every screen in your app, you could create a `BaseActivity` class and have all of your other activites extend that instead of `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.action_bar);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fits what I want but I have a question. Isn't there anyway to do this from styles.xml?